# Error in JavaScript addToDoButton.addEventListener("click", function(){

Tags: javascript, html

What have I done wrong? Here is what the result tells me:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: addToDoButton is not defined

Here is my JavaScript:

```
let addToDo = document.getElementById("edit_button");
let toDoContainer = document.getElementById("to_do_container");
let inputField = document.getElementById("inputField");

addToDoButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
     var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
     paragraph.classList.add("paragraph-styling");
     paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
     toDoContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
     inputField.value = " ";
     paragraph.addEventListener("click", function(){
         paragraph.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
     })
     paragraph.addEventListener("dblclick", function(){
         paragraph.removeChild(paragraph)
     })
})
```

Here is my HTML:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet", href="style.css">
        <h1 class="tdl_header">TO DO LIST</h1>
    </head>

    <body class="body">
            <div class="container">
                <input id="inputField" type = "text" 
                placeholder="add your list"> 
                <button id="addToDo"> + </button>
                <div class="to-dos" id="toDoContainer" >
                </div>
            </div>
            <script src="to_do_list.js"></script>
            
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
let addToDo = document.getElementById("edit_button");
let toDoContainer = document.getElementById("to_do_container");
let inputField = document.getElementById("inputField");

addToDoButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
  paragraph.classList.add("paragraph-styling");
  paragraph.innerText = inputField.value;
  toDoContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
  inputField.value = " ";
  paragraph.addEventListener("click", function() {
    paragraph.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  })
  paragraph.addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
    paragraph.removeChild(paragraph)
  })
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" , href="style.css">
  <h1 class="tdl_header">TO DO LIST</h1>
</head>

<body class="body">
  <div class="container">
    <input id="inputField" type="text" placeholder="add your list">
    <button id="addToDo"> + </button>
    <div class="to-dos" id="toDoContainer">
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="to_do_list.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The error pretty much says it all, `addToDoButton` doesn't appear to exist at the point it's used.

Comment: "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: addToDoButton is not defined"

Comment: your head element containing an `h1` is invalid

Answer (score 2):

You called your variable `addToDo` but want to add the listener to `addToDoButton` which doesn't exist.

EDIT:
As @Beriu mentioned, the id of the button also doesn't match the string in the selector.

Comment: And also  **<button id="addToDo"> + </button>** the id is **addToDo** not **edit_button**

Comment: thank you! By the way my paragraph.removeChild doesnt work, what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues there:

1. you want to select a button wiht `getElementById('edit_button')` which doesn't exists
2. you want to `addEventListener` to a DOM element which can't be selcted

Solution:

```
let addToDo = document.getElementById("addToDo");
let toDoContainer = document.getElementById("to_do_container");
let inputField = document.getElementById("inputField");

addToDo.addEventListener("click", function() {
// your code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you attach your event handler for the click and double click on the "tasks" to the container, then it is easier to use the `event.target` for the action to take place.
I did some rework of class and id to make them more consistent and match the event handler attachment here also.
I also do not append "blank" tasks.

```js
function handleToDoPlus(event) {
  let inputField = document.getElementById("input-field");
  let newValue = inputField.value;
  let hasValue = newValue.length > 0
  event.target.nextElementSibling.innerText = hasValue ? "" : "No Value Entered";
  if (hasValue) {
    let paragraph = document.createElement("p");
    paragraph.classList.add("paragraph-styling");
    paragraph.innerText = newValue;
    let toDoContainer = document.getElementById("to-do-container");
    toDoContainer.appendChild(paragraph);
    inputField.value = "";
  }
}

function handleDoubleClick(event) {
  console.log('double click!');
  if (event.target.className === 'paragraph-styling') {
    event.currentTarget.removeChild(event.target)
  }
}

function handleClickToDone(event) {
  console.log('Click!');
  if (event.target.className === 'paragraph-styling') {
    event.target.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
  }
}


let addToDo = document.getElementById("add-to-do");
addToDo.addEventListener("click", handleToDoPlus);
let toDoContainer = document.getElementById("to-do-container");
toDoContainer.addEventListener("dblclick", handleDoubleClick);
toDoContainer.addEventListener("click", handleClickToDone);
//let inputField = document.getElementById("input-field");
```

```css
.error-message {
  color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="input-field" type="text" placeholder="add your list">
  <button id="add-to-do"> + </button> <span class="error-message"></span>
  <div id="to-do-container" class="to-dos">
  </div>
</div>
```